# Clear HTTP Session

Tags: java, html

I am trying to clear everything on my HTML form when I visit it from a hyperlink entry.

Any ideas? My development language is java.

Comment: You'd need to trap an event. Might want to use something like jQuery.

Comment: Details and code (jsp???) absent.

Answer (score 0):

are you using session-scoped data? if so, close your browser and open it again.

Comment: or programmaticaly close the session :)

Comment: I'm not sure if he's talking about from a user's perspective or a developer's perspective

Comment: oh sorry...i meant from a development perspective

Comment: How would you guys clear all the contents of a HTTP session programatically?

Comment: Is this question even worthy enough to post?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the application is, but one way to accomplish this would be to use JavaScript. For example, if it is acceptable to clear the form every time that page is visited you could write a quick function that clears the form when the page is loaded (i.e., using the `onload` event).

If you only want to clear the form when the page is hit from that link you could add a param to the URL (e.g., clearForm=true) and use JavaScript to pick up the query string and clear the form when that parameter is present.

This is, of course, a purely client-side solution. For a server-side solution it would be helpful to know what framework you are using.

Comment: I actually added three lines of code to one of my jsps and it seems to be working fine. I am calling the invalidate method of httpsession which clears the session when the application reaches that particular jsp...